# キャッシュがあった場合、処理をskipする方法はあるのでしょうか？

Tags: circleci

現在、CircleCIのver2を使っているのですが、キャッシュが効いていた場合、ダウンロード処理をスキップしたいですのですが、やり方がわかりません。

具体的な私のシチュエーションを書くと、
私はあるファイルをネット上から落として展開してリネームするという処理を書いています。それをCircleCIのキャッシュ機能を使って、もしデータがキャッシュされていればそれを使用、無ければダウンロードしてくるという処理を書きたいです。

よく公式などに乗っているのは以下のようなキャッシュ方法だと思います。

```
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - gem-cache-v1-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}

      - run: bundle install --path vendor/bundle

      - save_cache:
          key: gem-cache-v1-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle
```

この方法だとrestore_cacheでキャッシュがヒットしても後続のbundle installは実行されると思います。
bundle installだと差分を計算して実行するので良いとは思いますが、今私がやろうとしているのはこのrun部分をスキップしたいです。

何か良い方法はないでしょうか？ご回答お待ちしております。

Comment: `キャッシュが存在するがGemfileが変更されており再度bundle installする必要がある` という場合にもスキップしてしまいそうですが、問題ありませんか？

Comment: こちらは例ですので、問題ないと思っています。

Comment: user3387068さん、ご質問に対してご自身が解決を諦めた際には、特に何もしていただかなくて結構です :)　スタック・オーバーフローはQ&Aのwikiのようなもので、質問者さんがいなくなった後もQ&Aのメンテナンスが続きます。また、回答になっていない回答は、申し訳ないのですが削除となってしまいます。もし気になるようであれば、質問文末尾に追記として書き残すことは可能です。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。